# Control Offline Windows XP Machine Through Steam Link

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, local, logitech-gamepad, steam-link

I have a windows xp retro game machine that is permanently disconnected from the internet. I am hoping to use this computer remotely through a Logitech G Cloud Handheld.

Right now my current theory is to use my modern pc with a capture card to send a video stream through steam link. at the same time, send the G Cloud inputs back to the modern pc through steam link, and forward these inputs to the retro pc by some type of cable.

Is there any way to "export" the modern pc's inputs that are coming in virtually, to have the retro pc recognize them as normal usb mouse/controller inputs?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Feels like a job for [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy). You can share your inputs through a home network not necessarily connected to the web.